# 【Excel.Worksheet.onChanged】I only changed the range value once, but the callback was run many times. Why is that？

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a feature,Listen for changes in one range and assign values to another range.

My implementation steps：

1.Use the onChanged event to listen for changes to the data.

2.Assign the changed value【event.details.valueAfter】 to the target range in the callback function.

This is my code：
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lealz.png

But the console will show that it ran the callback many times,This is the console log：
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS941.png

Is there something wrong with my code?Is there a good solution?

Comment: console.log('1111111');  Add semicolon here and then try and also add semicolon in the end of function, you missed that one

Comment: If you're changing the worksheet every time the worksheet changes, it will just keep triggering that event listener.

Comment: @Manoj Tolagekar  First of all thank you for your answer.I've tried it and it's the same

Comment: @Andrew .First of all thank you for your answer.But I only modified the range once.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Excel js API, but I wonder if you could use event.triggerSource to determine whether the addin triggered the event, and return early if it did. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetchangedeventargs?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-worksheetchangedeventargs-triggersource-member

Comment: @cloud.yao but aren't you changing the range inside the event handler? Which in turn triggers the listener again, which then modifies the range again, and again, and again ...

Comment: sheet.onchanged((event)) instead of add this sheet.onchanged(event)

Comment: @Andrew  Thank you very much for your help, which made me understand a lot

Comment: @Manoj Tolagekar   Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant

Comment: why you have added extra bracket

Comment: @Manoj Tolagekar  That is a javascript syntax, removing parentheses and enclosing parentheses does not affect the program to run